# Approximation by definite integrals

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I've seen a statement that says if $f$ is decreasing and continuous, then we have the following relation between the sum and integral:

$$ \int_a^{b+1} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{i=a}^b f(i) \leq \int_{a-1}^b f(x)dx$$

I was wondering how to show this. I would be glad if I could get some help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be two integers then:

$$\int_{a}^{b+1}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=a}^{b}\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx\le\sum_{k=a}^{b}f(k)$$

since $f$ is decreasing (where I have used that $f(k)\ge f(x)$ for $x\in[k,k+1]$). Similarly

$$\int_{a-1}^{b}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=a}^{b}\int_{k-1}^{k}f(x)dx\ge\sum_{k=a}^{b}f(k)$$

Comment: I dont understand the first inequality

Comment: Since $f(k)\ge f(x)$ for $x\in[k,k+1]$ then integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives $f(k)=\int_{k}^{k+1}f(k)dx\ge\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx.$

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$\inf_{x\in [n, n+1]}f(x)\int_{n}^{n+1}dx\leq \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx \leq \displaystyle\sup_{x\in [n, n+1]}f(x)\int_{n}^{n+1}dx$$

If $f$ is decreasing, then the left-most is equal to $f(n+1)$ and the right-most is equal to $f(n)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: try to interpret the three terms as the areas of three regions of the plane, delimited by the $x$ axis and the graph of $f$ or, for the middle one, by an opportune piecewise constant approximation of $f$. Then sketch those regions.

They say a picture says more than a 1000 words.